# Replacing ItemsControl ContentPresenter entirely with control being rendered

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml

i'm using an ItemsControl to generate a list of controls based on my model.
When looking at the visual tree, i noticed that each of the rendered control is wrapped in a ContentPresenter.  The controls that are added are a 3rd party control and are designed to display a splitter between each control if they are siblings..this allows a user to size each control. For example the following will show a splitter between each of the controls at run time.

```
<StackPanel>
<3rdPartyControl />
<3rdPartyControl />
<3rdPartyControl />
</StackPanel>
```

When using an ItemsControl, each of the 3rdPartyControl are wrapped in a ContentPresenter, and thus no splitter is shown.  I have tried various ways to try and solve this problem but unable to get this to work unless i write code behind to add each control rather than rely on Xaml.
Does anyone know of a way to replace the contentpresenter completely (in my case with 3rdpartyControl)?

Thanks

Comment: why do you think ContentPresenter is the reason that splitter doesn't work?

Comment: because if i add 3 of the controls as in my example without using an ItemsControl, it works as expected.  Using snoop to look at the difference, i see that in the case it doesn't work, the contentpresenter wraps the controls...that's the only difference.

Comment: Is this when you even specify your own ItemsPanelTemplate (StackPanel) for the ItemsControl?

Comment: ItemsPanel template will wrap the entire list of items i believe.  What i need is to generate a visual tree w/o that ContentPresenter around each control that is generated.  Out of desparatio and curiousity..i tried specifying a custom ItemsControl.ItemsPanel, ItemsControl.Template and ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle to get these controls to render as sequential siblings.  In none of these cases did the expected behavior work and when checking the visual tree, i continue to see each of the controls wrapped by ContentPresenter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to replace the ContentPresenter you could derive from ItemsControl and override the [GetContainerForItemOverride](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.getcontainerforitemoverride.aspx) method to create a specialized container control.

ListBox for example overrides this method to create a ListBoxItem as container for a new item object.

Comment: This seems to do the trick, but for some reason it is not calling my DataTemplate to render content.  i do see the custom controls in the visual tree however..they just have no content.  not sure why...

Comment: In order to make a DataTemplate work, you'd need a control that can deal with a DataTemplate (ContentPresenter for example :-). You can however provide a Style for your container by setting the [ItemContainerStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainerstyle.aspx) property.

Comment: hmmm..this is getting messy. the new container is a DevExpress LayoutGroup control to which i want to add a chart control as a child...the LayoutGroup doesn't even have a template  property.

Comment: Sorry, i don't know that one.

Comment: that's ok, i think your answer will be helpful to others encountering the same issue. thanks

Comment: But you may always also override [PrepareContainerForItemOverride](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.preparecontainerforitemoverride.aspx) to apply a style etc.

Comment: im thinking of trying to expose ContentPresenter as a dependency property of LayoutGroup and see if i can get the custom ItemsControl to apply the datatemplate as it normally would if the container was a content presenter

Answer (score 0):

That's true, every element that you add to ItemsControl is wrapped with ContentPresenter, you can find more details about it in the greate series of articles from dr.wpf [ItemsControl a-z](http://drwpf.com/blog/itemscontrol-a-to-z/)

One way I would suggest to try is to change ItemsControl to ListBox and make ListBox act like ItemsControl. In this case you can re-style/re-template ListBoxItem and replace ContentPresenter with your control. You would also need to stop selection support. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754242.aspx) is ListBox style that you need to change.

Comment: I did try using a listbox by re-templating...but if recall, the issue here is similar, each control rendered is wrapped in a ListBoxItem.